# In probability theory, what are the definitions of "high probability", "overwhelming probability", and "$\Omega(n)$"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation, terminology

While studying results related to concentration inequalities in probability, I keep seeing the terms "high probability", "overwhelming probability", and the symbol $\Omega(n)$.

Can someone please tell me what their *precise mathematical definitions* are?

Comment: cf. [big omega notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) for $\Omega(n)$

Comment: @lulu Surprisingly (to me anyways) they turn out to be techncial terms, at least sometimes - see Tao's post mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  That is really surprising.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of "high probability" and "overwhelming probability" can be found in [these notes of Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/) just after Definition $1$. They respectively refer to an event holding with probability $1-O(n^{-c})$ for some $c$ independent of $n$ and holding with probability $1-O_A(n^{-A})$ for each $A>0$.

$\Omega(x)$ meanwhile is one of the various *asymptotic behavior* notations, along with $O(x)$; it's described on the wikipedia page for [big $O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation). Unfortunately (as is said there) there are really *two* different definitions of $\Omega$ and only context can indicate which is intended.

Comment: Thank you! That helped!